# Python filter nested dict with key value and print a part

Tags: python, dictionary

Let´s say I have a nested `dict` like this but much longer:

```
    {
"problems": [{
                "1":[{
                        "name":"asprin abc",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"100 mg"
                    }],


                "2":[{

                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strenght":"51g"

                    }],
                "3":[{

                        "name":"againSomethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strenght":"511g"

                    }],           
        }],
        "labs":[{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }]
    }
```

Now I want to iterate through the `dict` and do some filtering. I just want to have the part where the key `"name"` is `LIKE '%aspirin%`, as in `Transact-SQL`.

So the output should be the following:

```
[{
  "name":"asprin abc",
  "dose":"",
  "strength":"100 mg"
}]
```

I now how to iterate through the `dict` but I don´t know how I should achieve the value filtering where I print the whole part where the title matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a general solution making no assumption on the structure of the passed object, which could be a list, dictionary, etc. It will recursively descend throug the structure looking for a dictionary with a key `"name"` whose value contains `asprin` and will `yield` that dictionary:

```
d = {
"problems": [{
                "1":[{
                        "name":"asprin abc",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strength":"100 mg"
                    }],


                "2":[{

                        "name":"somethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strenght":"51g"

                    }],
                "3":[{

                        "name":"againSomethingElse",
                        "dose":"",
                        "strenght":"511g"

                    }],
        }],
        "labs":[{
            "missing_field": "missing_value"
        }]
    }

def filter(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            yield from filter(item)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if "name" in obj and "asprin" in obj["name"]:
            yield obj
        else:
            for v in obj.values():
                if isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
                    yield from filter(v)

print(list(filter(d)))
```

Prints:

```
[{'name': 'asprin abc', 'dose': '', 'strength': '100 mg'}]
```

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/kHbwZN)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below:

```
for p_obj in json_data["problems"]:
    for i in p_obj.keys():
        for j in p_obj[i]:
            if "asprin" in j["name"]:
                output.append(j)
print(output)
```

Comment: Don't use `str.find()` when `in` would do: `if "asprin" in j["name"]:`

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution like described above. A list comprehension is much easier

```
[problem for problem in problem['problems'] if problem['name'].find("aspirin")!=1]
```

Comment: I am having trouble following. I assume that you are assuming the name of the `dict` is `problem`. But `problem[`problems`]  has no key named `name`. Did you run this? Could you show all the code? Thanks.